# F# syntax for async controller methods in ASP.NET Core

Tags: f#, asp.net-core

I'm new to F# and trying to translate some C# ASP.NET Core code into F#

There is a C# controller [here](https://github.com/joeaudette/playground/blob/master/spa-stack/src/CSharp.WebLib/Controllers/ToDoController.cs), and a working translated F# controller [here](https://github.com/joeaudette/playground/blob/master/spa-stack/src/FSharp.WebLib/Controllers.fs)

even though I got it working, I can't seem to figure out how to make the controller actions async. The methods call async code on a Commands object and a Queries object that are injected. The Commands and Queries are currently implemented in C#.

So for example a couple of the async C# controller methods are:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ToDoItem>> Get()
    {
        return await queries.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(string id)
    {
        var item = await queries.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] ToDoItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Id)) item.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        await commands.Add(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.Id }, item);
    }
```

and I've translated those to F# like this:

```
    [<HttpGet>]
    member __.Get() =
           __.Queries.GetAll() // this should be awaited

    [<HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetFSTodo")>]
    member __.GetToDoItem(id) = 
        let data = __.Queries.Find(id) // this should be awaited
        if isNull data 
            then  __.NotFound() :> IActionResult
            else
            new ObjectResult(data) :> IActionResult 

    [<HttpPost>]
    member __.Create([<FromBody>] item:ToDoItem) = 
        item.Id <- Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        (__.Commands.Add(item)) |> ignore // this should be awaited
        let rv = new RouteValueDictionary()
        rv.Add("id",item.Id)
        __.CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", rv, item) :> IActionResult
```

These methods work but I think they are not correctly done since they aren't awaiting the async calls on Queries and Commands. I've thrashed for some hours with trial and error but every attempt I've made to make the controller methods async results in them not returning any data to the browser even though they return a 200 status code. You can see some of my attempts commented out in the [F# controller](https://github.com/joeaudette/playground/blob/master/spa-stack/src/FSharp.WebLib/Controllers.fs)

Hoping some F# guru(s) could help me translate those methods correctly. There are some pretty bad tooling issues currently in terms of F# with ASP.NET Core which makes it more difficult for a newbie like me. I've mentioned those issues in the [readme](https://github.com/joeaudette/playground/tree/master/spa-stack)

There are a few additional methods in the code but I figure if I can learn how to solve for these methods then the same solution will probably apply to the other methods.

The code is in a public repository so you can easily try it in VS 2015 as long as you have the latest VS updates and the latest ASP.NET Core tooling installed

UPDATE:

thanks to the linked post by Mark Seemann, I was able to get this method working async

```
[<HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetFSTodo")>]
member __.GetToDoItem(id) = 
    async {
        let! data = __.Queries.Find(id) |> asyncReturn
        if isNull data 
            then return  __.NotFound() :> IActionResult
            else
                return new ObjectResult(data) :> IActionResult  } 
        |> Async.StartAsTask
```

by using the helper function

```
let asyncReturn x = async { return x }
```

I'm still struggling with this method

```
[<HttpGet>]
member __.Get() =
    async {
           let! data = __.Queries.GetAll() |> asyncReturn
           return data  }
        |> Async.StartAsTask
```

which is translated from this C# method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<ToDoItem>> Get()
{
    return await queries.GetAll();
}
```

the async F# method works but it produces different json output than the C# version

```
C#
[{"id":"4f4e1596-6a48-4854-9982-7a2568aa1b1b","title":"add input validation","isDone":false,"dateAdded":"2016-09-20T21:16:04.8791044Z"},{"id":"9929b657-6a53-40b6-8c1c-1e4d0db593cd","title":"make F# controller async","isDone":false,"dateAdded":"2016-09-21T19:36:44.6650776Z"},{"id":"5bb5f544-6289-4051-ad65-d0dc016128e7","title":"learn F# basics","isDone":true,"dateAdded":"2016-09-22T11:59:00"},{"id":"e5e06118-c49f-496a-8175-9719ea72beed","title":"monkey business","isDone":false,"dateAdded":"2016-09-22T16:22:20.3133161Z"},{"id":"af0db8f2-6b49-4e31-86fa-e27c8e091f42","title":"funky bidness","isDone":false,"dateAdded":"2016-09-22T16:23:35.1175195Z"}]

F#
{"result":[{"id":"4f4e1596-6a48-4854-9982-7a2568aa1b1b","title":"add input validation","isDone":false,"dateAdded":"2016-09-20T21:16:04.8791044Z"},{"id":"9929b657-6a53-40b6-8c1c-1e4d0db593cd","title":"make F# controller async","isDone":false,"dateAdded":"2016-09-21T19:36:44.6650776Z"},{"id":"5bb5f544-6289-4051-ad65-d0dc016128e7","title":"learn F# basics","isDone":true,"dateAdded":"2016-09-22T11:59:00"},{"id":"e5e06118-c49f-496a-8175-9719ea72beed","title":"monkey business","isDone":false,"dateAdded":"2016-09-22T16:22:20.3133161Z"},{"id":"af0db8f2-6b49-4e31-86fa-e27c8e091f42","title":"funky bidness","isDone":false,"dateAdded":"2016-09-22T16:23:35.1175195Z"}],"id":65,"exception":null,"status":5,"isCanceled":false,"isCompleted":true,"creationOptions":0,"asyncState":null,"isFaulted":false}
```

so I still could use some help on how to make the F# version produce the expected output

Comment: try Async.AwaitTask

Comment: You can see an example of an async Controller Action towards the end of this blog post: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/04/11/async-as-surrogate-io Does that help?

Comment: @mark-seemann thanks! I've got some progress thanks to your post, and have updated my question hoping for further insight

Comment: What is the return type of `queries.GetAll()`?

Comment: it returns a [Task of List of ToDoItem](https://github.com/joeaudette/playground/blob/master/spa-stack/src/CSharp.Storage.NoDb/ToDoQueries.cs)

Comment: when I look at the F# json output it makes me think I'm getting back a tuple and the first element in the tuple is the List of ToDoItem and the second element is some kind of indicator about the task execution outcome. so I need to get the first element somehow and just return it

Comment: figured it out, need to return data.Result, seems to get back a tuple with Result, AsyncState

Comment: if it's Task of List, you want `Async.AwaitTask` and a `let!` to await. if it's `Task<Tuple<x,y>>`, you want `let! (x,y) = doit()` (with an `Async.AwaitTask` if necessary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATED 2016-09-28

Thanks to Ruben Bartelink this is what my controller looks like now correctly implemented as async and handling the nuances that differ between C# and F# async patterns:

```
namespace FSharp.WebLib

open System
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch
open FSharp.Models

module ActionResult =
    let ofAsync (res: Async<IActionResult>) =
        res |> Async.StartAsTask

[<Route("api/[controller]")>]
type FSToDoController(commands: IToDoCommands, queries: IToDoQueries) =
    inherit Controller()

    [<HttpGet>]
    member this.Get() = 
        ActionResult.ofAsync <| async {
            let! data = queries.GetAll()
            return JsonResult(data) :> _ } 

    [<HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetFsToDo")>]
    member this.Get(id) =
        ActionResult.ofAsync <| async {
            let! res = queries.Find id
            match res with 
            | None -> return this.NotFound() :> _
            | Some data -> return ObjectResult(data) :> _ } 

    // create
    [<HttpPost>]
    member this.Post([<FromBody>] item:ToDoItem) =
        ActionResult.ofAsync <| async {
            if not this.ModelState.IsValid then
                return this.BadRequest() :> _
            else  
                let item = { item with Id = Guid.NewGuid() |> string }
                do! commands.Add item
                let rv = RouteValueDictionary()
                rv.Add("id",item.Id)
                return this.CreatedAtRoute("GetFsToDo", rv, item) :> _ } 

    // update
    [<HttpPut("{id}")>]
    member this.Put(id:String, [<FromBody>] item:ToDoItem) =
        ActionResult.ofAsync <| async {
            if (not this.ModelState.IsValid) || String.IsNullOrEmpty item.Id then
                return this.BadRequest() :> _
            else
                let! res = queries.Find id
                match res with
                | None -> return this.NotFound() :> _
                | Some toDo ->
                    do! commands.Update item
                    return NoContentResult() :> _ }
```

for anyone else interested in learning F# particularly for use in ASP.NET Core, this is part of a [proof of concept project on github](https://github.com/joeaudette/playground/blob/master/spa-stack/README.md) that has both C# and F# implementations of a ToDo list back end web api both of which are consumed from a front end implemented with polymer web components. Models and data access are also implemented in both languages to provide a good comparison for C# devs like myself to learn F#

Comment: you can declare the methods as `:IActionResult` and replace the `:> IActionResult` in the bodies with with `:> _`. For `(__.Commands.Add(item)) |> asyncReturn |> ignore`, you should just be able to either `do! __.Commands.Add(item)` (if it returns `Async<unit>` or else `do!` with `|> ignore` or `let! _ = cmd...`. IOW don't go down the reoad of `asyncReturn`

Comment: thank you @RubenBartelink! I've updated my answer with improvements based on your suggestions but could not get it to compile if I make the suggested change about declare the methods as IActionResult, maybe I did it incorrectly, I linked a gist to show my attempt

Comment: that's because I hadn't thought it through. The result should be Task<IActionResult> for the `:> _` to work. Also if you are actually using the `this`, don't call it `__` :). And `Option.ofObj` is the best OOTB (F#4) way to deal with an if around a `null` (and it generalises better if e.g. you do validation using http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop). And ` do! Async.AwaitTask(__.Commands.Add(item))` is better written `do! this.Commands.Add item |> Async.AwaitTask`. If you stick a sln with a fsproj on github I'm happy to polish. IIRC panesofglass has a F# ToDoMvc impl worth looking at too

Comment: Will comment on gist too

Comment: thanks again! the Option.ofObj works but the Task<IActionResult> still fails to compile, I've updated the gist

Comment: the solution is here and I've added you as a collaborator if you would like to try to improve it which will help me learn F#, but it is .xproj not .fsproj since it is asp.net core https://github.com/joeaudette/playground

Comment: It's been a while but do you happen to remember why exactly you got 200 but an empty response body? I'm having the same problems but using your suggested solution here does not resolve it