# Updating an F# ASP.NET Core app from .NET 3.1 to 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

I was taking a look at the following tutorial:

[F# REST API: A step by step using Entity Framework Core, MVC, and PostgreSQL](https://medium.com/swlh/f-rest-api-net-core-using-entity-framework-mvc-and-postgresql-fc7643faa747)

I implemented the steps on .NET 5.0.100. I had to change a few items in the project and it eventually compiled.

The following method:

```
[<HttpGet>]
member this.Get() =
    ActionResult<IEnumerable<ToDoItem>>(this._Context.ToDoItems)
```

works fine when I test it:

[image]

However, when I test this method:

```
[<HttpGet("{id}")>]
member this.Get(id:int) = 
    if base.ModelState.IsValid then  //check the entry
        if not ( this._Context.ToDoItemExist(id) ) then //check the existence of the ToDoItem
            ActionResult<IActionResult>(base.NotFound("NOT FOUND!, There is no ToDoItem with this code: " + id.ToString())) // ToDoItem does not exist
        else
            ActionResult<IActionResult>(base.Ok(this._Context.GetToDoItem(id)))
    else
        ActionResult<IActionResult>(base.BadRequest(base.ModelState))
```

I get the following:

[image]

What's a good way to resolve this?

## Project location

My version of the project is at:

https://github.com/dharmatech/luz-todo-fs

It compiles and runs on WSL.

The method mentioned above is in [Controllers/ToDoItemsController.fs](https://github.com/dharmatech/luz-todo-fs/blob/1fed2fa4d70bddfb9a9723c3b468d0622bd358b6/Controllers/ToDoItemsController.fs#L51).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that appears to work:

```
[<HttpGet("{id}")>]
member this.Get(id:int) =
    if base.ModelState.IsValid then
        if not (this._Context.ToDoItemExist(id)) then
            this.NotFound("NOT FOUND!, There is no ToDoItem with this code: " + id.ToString()) :> IActionResult
        else
            this.Ok(this._Context.GetToDoItem(id)) :> IActionResult

    else
        this.BadRequest(base.ModelState) :> IActionResult
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39648979/268581).